# Oracle 10g on MacOS Snow Leopard

Tags: oracle, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I've found this helpful tutorial on web

http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

I've followed all steps, but, I've a problem with netca run. When I'll start it, crash with this error:

Invalid memory access of location 00000014 eip=11069523
/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/bin/java: line 2: 10323 Bus error               /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Home/bin/java -d32 -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/lib/ext:/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/lib/ext $*

and the error message on popup show that the problem is with libnjni10.jnilib plugin. On snow leopard there is only Java 1.6 but I've installed also JDK1.5 and I've changed the symbolic link for 1.4.2 to run the 1.5

Any idea?

thanks a lot!
Andrea

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem on OS X Lion. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Alex Gorbachev's install guide suggests a couple of different ways of resolving this problem - editing `runinstaller` or installing JDK 1.4.2.  [Check it out](http://www.pythian.com/news/1937/quick-install-guide-for-oracle-10g-release-2-on-mac-os-x-leopard-intel/).

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using VMWare**

Is this for development purposes?  I've been happy with installing Oracle on a VMWare Linux instance.  One nice feature is that I can prep my database as I like, take a VMWare snapshot, and roll back to the saved snapshot as necessary.